# PayPal Instant Payment Notification troubleshooting

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I have a PayPal IPN script that has been working properly for several years. The PayPal history indicates that they are still being sent properly and It shows a HTTP code of 200.  THe data no longer writes to the database.  THe code is below.  I have not changed anything in the script.  I have read that paypal no longer accepts HTTP 1.0 but that does not seem to apply here Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
<?php
   //Change these with your information
$paypalmode = ''; //Sandbox for testing or empty ''
$dbusername     = '************'; //db username
$dbpassword     = '************'; //db password
$dbhost     = '************'; //db host
$dbname     = '***************'; //db name

if($_POST)
{
    if($paypalmode=='sandbox')
    {
        $paypalmode     =   '.sandbox';
    }
    $req = 'cmd=' . urlencode('_notify-validate');
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
        $req .= "&$key=$value";
    }
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www'.$paypalmode.'.ipnpb.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr'); // added .ipnpb
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Host:www'.$paypalmode.'.ipnpb.sandbox.paypal.com'));
    $res = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0)
    {
        $transaction_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
        $payerid = $_POST['payer_id'];
        $firstname = $_POST['first_name'];
        $lastname = $_POST['last_name'];
        $payeremail = $_POST['payer_email'];
        $paymentdate = $_POST['payment_date'];
        $paymentstatus = $_POST['payment_status'];
        $mdate= date('Y-m-d h:i:s',strtotime($paymentdate));
        //$sender_email= $_POST['sender_email'];
        $custom= $_POST['custom'];
        $otherstuff = json_encode($_POST);

        $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbusername,$dbpassword);
        if (!$conn)
        {
         die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        }

        mysql_select_db($dbname, $conn);

        // insert in our IPN record table
        $query = "INSERT INTO ibn_table
        (itransaction_id,ipayerid,iname,iemail,itransaction_date, ipaymentstatus,ieverything_else, custom)
        VALUES
        ('$transaction_id','$payerid','$firstname $lastname','$payeremail','$mdate', '$paymentstatus','$otherstuff','$custom')";


        if(!mysql_query($query))
        {
            //mysql error..!
        }
        // mysql_close($conn);

    }

       //mysql_select_db($dbname, $conn);
        // Update sender email
        //$query2 =  "UPDATE `ibn_table` SET `sender_email`=`iemail` WHERE `sender_email` = ''";
        //            if(!mysql_query($query2))
       //  {
            //mysql error..!
       //  }

      //  mysql_close($conn);
```

}

Comment: Id look at what paypal is sending back as res

Comment: The problem is with what paypal is sending back as res.  How do I see what is being sent back?

Comment: Looking at my old files, i used this after the $res
 $email_body = 'CURL'. "\n\n" . $req . "\n\n" . $res; 
tep_mail('', 'youremailaddress', 'ipm', $email_body, STORE_OWNER, STORE_OWNER_EMAIL_ADDRESS);